# Bêta testing app not found

Tags: android, google-play, google-groups

I've just put a Bêta APK of my app on the Developer Console. I've also created a Google Group and invited the people that can download the Bêta version of the app.
Google gives you a link in this format :
`https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.app.package`
Normally you would give this link to the testers, and if they actually exist in the Google Group they can open it and click the button `Become a Tester` and would be able to download the bêta version of the app directly from Google Play.
The problem is that some contacts, even though they actually exist in the group and **can** click on the button `Become a Tester`... they can't get to the page where they can download the app. A message is displayed saying :

> Not Found
>   We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.

Some users can download the app and others can't, even if they exist all in the same Google Group. Does anybody have any idea ?

Comment: Thoughts: Is the app compatable with all devices/countries? When did you upload the last APK? If it's a new APK, could it be that if takes different times to replicate the APK to different countries?

Comment: All users are in the same country. Some can download it and others can't, knowing that they all have GMail accounts...

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, and in my case it's my own account (i.e. the one that published the app, created the Google+ community and authorised the testers) that's not seeing the app! Other testers in the group are able to visit the page with no problems.

Comment: Any one you fixed this issue? I can't see my own app!

Comment: FWIW, my testers get this intermittently for no apparent reason. There is no correlation with when I've pushed up a new APK. Sometimes the link from the google community to the store works, sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same issue and it was caused by Google's multiple sign in (on desktop browsers).

I was signed in to my corporate account which I had authorised for testing, as well as my personal account which was not authorised. My corporate account is set as the default account, however when visiting the Play Store it was defaulting to my personal account (maybe because that's the one I use on my Android devices).

The problem can be solved by either authorising all signed in accounts for testing, or by signing out of unauthorised accounts.

Comment: That is it. Thank you very much. 
It is now clear that Google Play doesnt consider the app owner account as a tester by default. So, having a multiple account login(personal + app owner account) will result in "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server." even if the personal acc is a listed tester of the app.